# How to fork with reverse dependencies?

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php, git-fork

I forked `laravel/framework` and want to use clone's `testing-encoding` branch:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/x-yuri/framework"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "dev-testing-encoding"
    }
}
```

But when I do `composer require modelizer/selenium`, it says:

```
Using version ^1.1 for modelizer/selenium
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)                
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework 5.4.x-dev requires symfony/console 3.2.* -> satisfiable by symfony/console[3.2.x-dev, v3.2.0-BETA1, v3.2.0-RC1, v3.2.0-RC2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - laravel/framework 5.4.x-dev requires symfony/console 3.2.* -> satisfiable by symfony/console[3.2.x-dev, v3.2.0-BE
TA1, v3.2.0-RC1, v3.2.0-RC2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for modelizer/selenium ^1.1 -> satisfiable by modelizer/selenium[v1.1.0].
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework dev-testing-encoding
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework dev-testing-encoding
    - modelizer/selenium v1.1.0 requires laravel/framework ^5.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.4.x-dev, 5.1.x-de
v, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.1.x-dev, dev-testing-encoding].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.2.x-dev, dev-testing-encoding].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.3.x-dev, dev-testing-encoding].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[dev-testing-encoding, 5.1.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[dev-testing-encoding, 5.2.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[dev-testing-encoding, 5.3.x-dev].
    - Installation request for laravel/framework dev-testing-encoding -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[dev-testing-e
ncoding].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I tried to experiment with `minimum-stability`, and stability flags. To no avail. The best I could come up with is fork `modelizer/selenium` as well, and hardcode there `laravel`'s branch I need:

```
diff --git a/composer.json b/composer.json
index 9036e47..65facf0 100644
--- a/composer.json
+++ b/composer.json
@@ -12,8 +12,14 @@
             "email": "john.hoopes@madisoncreativeweb.com"
         }
     ],
+    "repositories": [
+        {
+            "type": "vcs",
+            "url": "https://github.com/x-yuri/framework"
+        }
+    ],
     "require": {
-        "laravel/framework": "^5.1",
+        "laravel/framework": "dev-testing-encoding",
         "symfony/process": ">=2.7",
         "phpunit/phpunit-selenium": ">=1.2",
         "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2"
```

Add the repo to root `composer.json`:

```
{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://github.com/x-yuri/Selenium"
}
```

And then do: `composer require modelizer/selenium=dev-laravel-testing-encoding`. Which also means, I've got to fork `laravel/socialite` too, though it doesn't require `laravel/framework` directly. Can it be any simpler than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guys on GitHub [helped](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5922#issuecomment-264129301) me with this one. As you can [see](https://github.com/Modelizer/Selenium/blob/v1.1.0/composer.json#L16), `modelizer/selenium` requires `laravel/framework=^5.1`. And we want `laravel/framework=dev-testing-encoding`. `composer` doesn't know how to compare these two versions, unless we tell it:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "dev-testing-encoding as 5.1.0"
}
```

This way, we convey to `composer` that `dev-testing-encoding` can be treated as version `5.1.0`. In other words, we alias `dev-testing-encoding` to `5.1.0`. As such, it satisfies `modelizer/selenium`'s dependency, and requiring the package succeeds.